# How to Print raw data in WPF

Tags: wpf, printing

I am looking at how to send raw data to a printer in WPF. This is similar to the Microsoft solution http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us however I want it to be in wpf vice using windows controls. Using the standard printing of wpf does not work as i need to send raw data vice the documentpage. I already know how to print the item but not get the printer name without doing a custom dialog or using winforms. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am printing to a thermal printer, this is why I can not use the printdocument or similar items in wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Sample code below:

```
using System.Printing;

PrintDialog _printDialog = new PrintDialog();
bool? _print = _printDialog.ShowDialog();

if (_print == true)
{
    string _printerName = **_printDialog.PrintQueue.FullName**;
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s)
}
```

RawPrinterHelper is from Microsoft Article above. to get the selected printer you need to use the PrintQueue.FullName property. Note the FullName may not show in Intellisense but does work.